# Renaming character variables in a column in data frame - R

Tags: r, dataframe, character, rename

I have a data frame that contains a column called ProjectSubject. The data frame is approximately 1,000,000 rows long.

Within the ProjectSubject column, I have lots of different strings. Here is an example:

```
>unique(unlist(projectdf$ProjectSubject))

[1] "Applied Learning"                           "Applied Learning, Literacy 
& Language"     
[3] "Literacy & Language"                        "Special Needs"                             
[5] "Literacy & Language, History & Civics"      "Math & Science"                            
[7] "History & Civics, Math & Science"           "Literacy & Language, 
Special Needs"        
[9] "Applied Learning, Special Needs"            "Health & Sports, Special 
Needs"            
[11] "Math & Science, Literacy & Language"        "Literacy & Language, Math 
& Science"       
[13] "Literacy & Language, Music & The Arts"      "Math & Science, Special 
Needs"             
[15] "Health & Sports"                            "Music & The Arts"                          
[17] "Math & Science, Applied Learning"           "Literacy & Language, 
Applied Learning"     
[19] "Applied Learning, Music & The Arts"         "History & Civics, 
Literacy & Language"     
[21] "Applied Learning, Math & Science"           "Health & Sports, Math & 
Science"           
[23] "Applied Learning, Health & Sports"          "History & Civics"                          
[25] "History & Civics, Music & The Arts"         "Math & Science, History & 
Civics"          
[27] "Math & Science, Music & The Arts"           "Special Needs, Music & 
The Arts"           
[29] "History & Civics, Applied Learning"         "History & Civics, Special 
Needs"
```

I need a succinct, non-manual way to go over the entire column in the data frame and replace a bunch of these strings with a different one. For example, I would like to replace "Applied Learning, Special Needs" with "Special Needs", or similarly replace "Applied Learning, Math & Science" with "Math".

I have about 50 unique strings much like the sample code given above that I want to reduce to about 10 unique strings. Preferably there is a method where I don't have to do this without manually typing a line of code for each of the 50 strings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a way I think is nice:

```
# first create some fake data that approximates your situation
set.seed(6933)

fruit_words <- c("apple", "orange", "banana", "pappels", "orong", "bernaner")

dat <- data.frame(fruit = sample(fruit_words, size=10, replace=TRUE), 
                  stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Create a table associating each unique value of `dat$fruit` with the desired category/string you want to substitute for it:

```
fruit_lkup <- c(apple="appl", orange="orng", banana="bnna", 
                pappels="appl", orong="orng", bernaner="bnna")
```

Then exploit the fact that `dat$fruit` holds the names of `fruit_lkup`

```
dat$fruit_clean <- as.character(fruit_lkup[dat$fruit])
```

And here's the result:

```
print(dat)
##       fruit   fruit_clean
## 1   pappels        appl
## 2     orong        orng
## 3     apple        appl
## 4    banana        bnna
## 5     apple        appl
## 6  bernaner        bnna
## 7  bernaner        bnna
## 8   pappels        appl
## 9  bernaner        bnna
## 10 bernaner        bnna
```

So really most of the work lies in creating the object you use to look up the values -- `fruit_lkup`.

One way to get started is just use `dput(unique(dat$fruit))`, then paste that into a script, and start supplying the values you want to replace.

If there's too many unique values, you could also write the unique values to a csv, and then manually add the values you want to replace after them. Then you could read in the (now) two-column csv as a data frame (say `lookup_df`), and create `fruit_lkup` with `fruit_lkup <- setNames(lookup_df$new_values, lookup_df$old_values)`

I've found this approach to be quite handy many times, in basically exactly the situation you describe.

Hope this helps ~~

Comment: I found this answer to be the best. This is simple and does not require tidyverse or other dependencies.

Comment: @Blacklivesmatter great to hear, that was the intention! base R is so underrated :p

Answer (score 1):

If you already know which strings you want to change, one solution could be to use `gsub`.

```
projectdf$ProjectSubject <- gsub("Applied Learning, Special Needs", "Special Needs", projectdf$ProjectSubject)
```

This would change the string "Applied Learning, Special Needs" to just ""Special Needs". It may be tedious with 50 `gsub` calls, so some clever regex may help to get around that issue. For example, if any string contains "Special Needs" at all, change to "Special Needs":

```
projectdf$ProjectSubject <- gsub("^.*?Special Needs", "Special Needs", projectdf$ProjectSubject)
```